# JSON serialization in JavaFX (with FXML and Controller)

Tags: java, json, serialization, javafx, jackson

So, I'm trying to serialize the values of a bunch of JavaFX controls (using FXML and a Controller) to a .JSON file, using the latest version of Jackson. I have two separate classes that I've written to make a Java Object that Jackson can serialize. I also have it so that the user can start the serialization process by clicking a (top level) menu in a menubar.

But whenever I try and test the application, it doesn't work (or give me any errors). What am I doing wrong? Does .JSON serialization work differently in JavaFX? Is it because I am using FXML and a controller? Or is it a problem with my code?

In my FXML:

```
        <Menu fx:id="GenerateJSONMenu" onAction="#GenerateJSONFiles" text="Generate ._JSON" />
```

In my Controller:

```
  public void GenerateJSONFiles(ActionEvent e)
  {   
    ObjectMapper JavaJSONMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectMapper KeybindsJSONMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try
    {
        JavaJSONMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File("config.json"), JSONWriter.class);
        KeybindsJSONMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File("keybinds.json"), KeybindsWriter.class);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

In JSONWriter.java:

```
package mcm_json_generator;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;


public class JSONWriter {
public String modName;
public String displayName;
public int minMcmVersion;
public String[] pluginRequirements;
public Content content[];
public Page pages[];

@JsonCreator
public JSONWriter(@JsonProperty("modName") String modName, @JsonProperty("displayName") String displayName, @JsonProperty("minMcmVersion") int minMcmVersion, @JsonProperty("pluginRequirements") String[] pluginRequirements, @JsonProperty("content") Content[] content, @JsonProperty("pages") Page[] pages){
    this.modName = modName;
    this.displayName = displayName;
    this.minMcmVersion = minMcmVersion;
    this.pluginRequirements = pluginRequirements;
    this.content = content;
    this.pages = pages;
}

public static  class Content {
   public String text;
   public String align;
   public String type;
   public String libName;
   public String className;

    @JsonCreator
    public Content(@JsonProperty(value="text", required=false) String text, @JsonProperty(value="align", required=false) String align, @JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty(value="libName", required=false) String libName, @JsonProperty(value="className", required=false) String className){
        this.text = text;
        this.align = align;
        this.type = type;
        this.libName = libName;
        this.className = className;
    }
}

public static  class Page {
   public String pageDisplayName;
   public Content content[];

    @JsonCreator
    public Page(@JsonProperty("pageDisplayName") String pageDisplayName, @JsonProperty("content") Content[] content){
        this.pageDisplayName = pageDisplayName;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public static  class Content {
       public String text;
       public String type;
       public Boolean html;
       public String id;
       public String help;
       public ValueOptions valueOptions;
       public Action action;

        @JsonCreator
        public Content(@JsonProperty(value="text", required=false) String text, @JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty(value="html", required=false) Boolean html, @JsonProperty(value="id", required=false) String id, @JsonProperty(value="help", required=false) String help, @JsonProperty(value="valueOptions", required=false) ValueOptions valueOptions, @JsonProperty(value="action", required=false) Action action){
            this.text = text;
            this.type = type;
            this.html = html;
            this.id = id;
            this.help = help;
            this.valueOptions = valueOptions;
            this.action = action;
        }

        public static  class ValueOptions {
           public int min;
           public int max;
           public int step;
           public String sourceType;

            @JsonCreator
            public ValueOptions(@JsonProperty("min") int min, @JsonProperty("max") int max, @JsonProperty("step") int step, @JsonProperty("sourceType") String sourceType){
                this.min = min;
                this.max = max;
                this.step = step;
                this.sourceType = sourceType;
            }
        }

        public static  class Action {
           public String type;
           public String form;
           public String function;
           public String[] params;

            @JsonCreator
            public Action(@JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty("form") String form, @JsonProperty("function") String function, @JsonProperty("params") String[] params){
                this.type = type;
                this.form = form;
                this.function = function;
                this.params = params;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In KeybindsWriter.Java:

```
package mcm_json_generator;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class KeybindsWriter {
public String modName;
public Keybind keybinds[];

@JsonCreator
public KeybindsWriter(@JsonProperty("modName") String modName, @JsonProperty("keybinds") Keybind[] keybinds){
    this.modName = modName;
    this.keybinds = keybinds;
}

public static class Keybind {
    public String id;
    public String desc;
    public Action action;

    @JsonCreator
    public Keybind(@JsonProperty("id") String id, @JsonProperty("desc") String desc, @JsonProperty("action") Action action){
        this.id = id;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.action = action;
    }

    public static class Action {
        public String type;
        public String form;

        @JsonCreator
        public Action(@JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty("form") String form){
            this.type = type;
            this.form = form;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "Does JSON serialization work differently in JavaFX"? No, JavaFX is the name of the library, but it is still the same Java.

Comment: If I look at your code I see lack of encapsulation and usage of arrays over Lists. Any reason for that?

Comment: Nope, not particularly. Just ended up that way.